# Inkscape - sculpting paths joining the ends unintentionally

Tags: inkscape, path

I've found some strange behave and I am not sure if this is my lack of knowledge or the application behavior.

I want to modify selection of bezier paths, although after I began using the sculpting tool, targeted paths are automatically joining the ends with another segment. I took a screenshot to illustrate this.

[image]

I tried simplified the paths, but it didn't change the result. Whats it about? The sculpting modification works, but its giving me this strange behavior in addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used that feature much myself, however it seems to convert open paths to closed paths - in fact it only seems to work properly with closed paths.

I tested this as follows.

1. I made a simple path, duplicated it and applied an interpolation of 20 steps.
2. I attempted to use the Tweak tool, but it turns the paths it touches into closed paths.
3. I then converted the paths to closed shapes using `Path` > `Stroke to path`. And now the tool works, but it creates literally thousands of nodes, and slows Inkscape down.

See my attempts here

[image: Screenshot of using the Tweak Tool]

Here's a close up of those thousands of nodes it creates. So, I'd use it with caution - especially when using it with so many curved shapes.

[image: Close up of nodes]